# how to download external files in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project which requires some data files available somewhere on the internet using http. The goal is that this immutable remote file is pulled once upon first build. Subsequent build should not download again.

How can I instruct gradle to fetch the given file to a local directory?

I've tried

```
task fetch(type:Copy) {
   from 'http://<myurl>'
   into 'data'
}
```

but it seems that copy task type cannot deal with http.

Bonus question: is there a way to resume a previously aborted/interrupted download just like `wget -c` does?

Comment: I've done this before using custom configurations, so that I can declare the resource as a versioned dependency. Then the normal resolution handling does its magic for you

Comment: There's a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327202/2873507

Answer (score 69):

How about just:

```groovy
def f = new File('the file path')
if (!f.exists()) {
    new URL('the url').withInputStream{ i -> f.withOutputStream{ it << i }}
}
```

Comment: Works well, but can you please suggest any pointers for directory download ?

Comment: How to do the same using Kotlin DSL ?

Comment: @SaurabhPadwekar in Kotlin DSL, you can use `val f = file("/tmp/file"); uri("http://example.com/index.html").toURL().openStream().use { it.copyTo(FileOutputStream(f)) }`

Answer (score 34):

You could probably use the [Ant task Get](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) for this. I believe this Ant task does not support resuming a download.

In order to do so, you can create a custom task with name `MyDownload`. That can be any class name basically. This custom task defines inputs and outputs that determine whether the task need to be executed. For example if the file was already downloaded to the specified directory then the task is marked UP-TO-DATE. Internally, this custom task uses the Ant task `Get` via the built-in `AntBuilder`.

With this custom task in place, you can create a new enhanced task of type `MyDownload` (your custom task class). This task set the input and output properties. If you want this task to be executed, hook it up to the task you usually run via task dependencies (`dependsOn` method). The following code snippet should give you the idea:

```groovy
task downloadSomething(type: MyDownload) {
    sourceUrl = 'http://www.someurl.com/my.zip'
    target = new File('data')
}

someOtherTask.dependsOn downloadSomething

class MyDownload extends DefaultTask {
    @Input
    String sourceUrl

    @OutputFile
    File target

    @TaskAction
    void download() {
       ant.get(src: sourceUrl, dest: target)
    }
}
```

Comment: Fyi all, you can set the ant proxy, using `ant.setproxy(proxyhost: System.props['http.proxyHost'], ...)`.

Comment: Always nice to see textbook authors answer questions on SO. This is extremely handy. Just used this to point to a binary release JAR file on GitHub. Thanks Benjamin!

Comment: I think with the `kotlin-dsl` you can do `ant.invokeMethod("get", mapOf("src" to sourceUrl, "dest" to target))` because of how the Groovy builder support works.

Answer (score 31):

Try like that:

```groovy
plugins {
    id "de.undercouch.download" version "1.2"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'

import de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.Download

task downloadFile(type: Download) {
    src 'http://localhost:8081/example/test-jar-test_1.jar'
    dest 'localDir'
}
```

You can check more here: https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task

For me works fine..

Comment: what is localDir

Answer (score 5):

The suggestion in Ben Manes's comment has the advantage that it can take advantage of maven coordinates and maven dependency resolution. For example, for downloading a Derby jar:

Define a new configuration:

```
configurations {
  derby
}
```

In the dependencies section, add a line for the custom configuration

```
dependencies {
  derby "org.apache.derby:derby:10.12.1.1"
}
```

Then you can add a task which will pull down the right files when needed (while taking advantage of the maven cache):

```
task deployDependencies() << {
   String derbyDir = "${some.dir}/derby"
   new File(derbyDir).mkdirs();
      configurations.derby.resolve().each { file ->
        //Copy the file to the desired location
        copy {
          from file 
          into derbyDir
          // Strip off version numbers
          rename '(.+)-[\\.0-9]+\\.(.+)', '$1.$2'
        }
      }
}
```

(I learned this from https://jiraaya.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/download-non-jar-dependency-in-gradle/).

Answer (score 4):

Using following plugin:

```
plugins {
    id "de.undercouch.download" version "3.4.3"
}
```

For a task which has the purpose of only downloading

```
task downloadFile(type: Download) {
    src DownloadURL
    dest destDir
}
```

For including download option into your task:

```
download {
    src DownloadURL
    dest destDir
}
```

For including download option with multiple downloads into your task:

```
task downloadFromURLs(){
    download {
        src ([
               DownloadURL1,
               DownloadURL2,
               DownloadURL3
        ])
        dest destDir
    }
}
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: how to add authentication also in task. If i have i want to pass username/password in my gradle task

Answer (score 2):

just now ran into [post on upcoming download task](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/download-files-with-progress-information-first-release-of-the-gradle-download-task-plugin-available/622) on gradle forum. 
Looks like the perfect solution to me.. Not (yet) available in an official gradle release though

Comment: Thx for notifying, I updated the url (gradle forum has been recently moved)

Comment: i'm sure it'll be listed in as "incubating" for years too </sarcasm>

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Version of @Benjamin's Answer

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
    }
}

tasks.register("downloadPdf"){
    val path = "myfile.pdf"
    val sourceUrl = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf"
    download(sourceUrl,path)
}

fun download(url : String, path : String){
    val destFile = File(path)
    ant.invokeMethod("get", mapOf("src" to url, "dest" to destFile))
}
```