# Download dependencies from url and extract to a folder using gradle

Tags: gradle

I am a gradle newbie. I see that gradle supports maven and ivy out of the box, however I have a need where the dependency for a java project is to be downloaded from a url. The dependencies are actually jar files which are zipped, I also need it to be extracted.

Comment: This may help for the download part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123606/how-to-download-external-files-in-gradle; unpacking can also be achieved with an ant task.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34327202/745574