# Can we use Maven Dependency in Gradle Project Remotely

Tags: maven, gradle

I am trying to host maven Dependency basically which I can use in Some other Gradle project.
I have also try this locally but I want to do it remotely.

I also try to do this in some other manner - I just host one jar file in tomcat server and tried to download in my gradle project.
"http://10.10.177.157:8080/face_rec/images/jmf-2.1.1e.jar" this is the hosted jar path in which we can eaisly download jar file by hitting this ulr.And "C:/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar" this is my local .m2 repository.

[In this gradle project I can easily download the jar files using **compile files ("C:/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar")** but I am not able to download hosted jars i.e - **http://10.10.177.157:8080/face_rec/images/jmf-2.1.1e.jar**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQMiv.png)

Can someone give me  any idea about this that how can it is possible.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to download external files in gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123606/how-to-download-external-files-in-gradle)

Comment: Please do not upload screenshots of your code, but add it in code blocks to your question.