# downloading jars / libraries through custom / third party URL in simple Gradle project

Tags: gradle

Can anybody help in downloading jars / libraries through custom / third party URL in simple Gradle project.

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to achieve and what you already tried for this goal.

Comment: Please refer this link for what I have done early http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114053/can-we-use-maven-dependency-in-gradle-project-remotely