# gradle + kotlin-dsl: download file

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How can I download a file within a **gradle task** with **kotlin-dsl**?

I want to download a file from an external source (URL) and store + rename it inside my projectfolder.

I tried to find solutions online I only found solutions written in groovy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17124000/2196460 It requires a custom class task, but that looks quite simple.

Comment: Alternatively, there's a plugin that can do that: https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task

Comment: If you struggle over translating a specific piece of a Groovy solution to Kotlin DSL, please ask a more specific question about that.

Comment: @hotkey how do i use this with kotlin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution using https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task:

```
import de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.Download

...

plugins {
  ....
  id("de.undercouch.download").version("3.4.3")
}

...

task<DefaultTask>("my-download-task") {
  ...
  val url = " ... "
  val dest = File("...")
  task<Download>("download-task") {
    src(url)
    dest(dest)
  }
  dependsOn("download-task")
}
```

Comment: I am new to kotlin gradle but adding the plugin in the same files gave me this error :
The plugins {} block must not be used here. If you need to apply a plugin imperatively, please use apply<PluginType>()

Answer (score 5):

Simple with no external dependency.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
    }
}

tasks.register("downloadPdf"){
    val path = "myfile.pdf"
    val sourceUrl = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf"
    download(sourceUrl,path)
}

fun download(url : String, path : String){
    val destFile = File(path)
    ant.invokeMethod("get", mapOf("src" to url, "dest" to destFile))
}
```