# Gradle dependencies to download a single file from github repository

Tags: github, gradle

Need some help with writing the gradle dependices  to download a single file from github repository

We have a scenario where we need to download .yaml file from the github repository so that we can use it further to autogenerarte it . How do I download a single file form github report via gradle

Comment: A `build.gradle` file is basically just Groovy. You can use there what the language provides. Alternatively you could try to find a plugin that does it.

Comment: Hi Henry, I m very new to Gradle dont have any idea how to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to download external files in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123606/how-to-download-external-files-in-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

The best option, if you have freedom to change the source project, is for the yaml to be built, versioned and published to a repository. Eg packed inside a zip/jar in nexus. You could then get the zip/jar in Gradle similar to any other dependency then unpack the yaml file.

Failing that there's a couple of options with github

1. Download via http (see [download plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/de.undercouch.download))
2. Get using git (see [gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) plugin)

Comment: Can some please help me understand where is it I m going wrong ?

Comment: My file SimpleTask.gradle looks like this `buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:3.4.3"
  }
}

apply plugin: "de.undercouch.download"

task downloadFile(type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/qlik-trial/qix-data-reload/blob/master/api-docs.yml'
    dest 'Artifactory'
}`

Comment: `gradlew.bat -b simpleTask.gradle downloadFile  --no-daemon --refresh-dependencies --stacktrace  --warning-mode all`

Comment: It is downloadin me all other files but nothing from github