# Download Android string resources at build time

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I work on an app, where we have the different translations of the strings.xml file online to crowdsource translations. The translation tool offers an API for accessing the xml files per URL.

e.g.: `https://localise.biz/api/export/locale/en.xml?format=android&key=7qUo-LUKd4VIHSwRYB5005T7QQbaFCGw`

Is it possible to download and include those files when the gradle build starts?

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: I think you need to create a custom task to first download files (check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17124244) and then call the build task to build  the project.

Comment: If it doesn't work, try using a download plugin for Gradle. There are abundant such plugins: https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=Download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IamAshKS served me the answer. I solved it like this:

```
task downloadTranslations {
   group 'pre-build tasks'
   description 'Downloads all translation files when building the app.'

   ext.apiKey = '7qUo-LUKd4VIHSwRYB5005T7QQbaFCGw'

   //English
   doLast {
      def f = new File("${project.projectDir}/src/main/res/values/strings.xml")
      new URL("https://localise.biz/api/export/locale/en.xml?format=android&key=${apiKey}").withInputStream{ i -> f.withOutputStream{ it << i }}
   }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help! Now, I only have to get it running before the actual build.

Comment: It's great that it worked for you. I'm not sure you put the actual API key or not, but it's good practice to not put API keys on Stack Overflow or any public page or website. Thanks!

Comment: There's no security issue here. It is only an export key. No write access with that key.

Comment: Oh, in that case, great!